# Regex for Phone field

Tags: regular-expressions

I need a regex for a phone number in this format

### #######

The 3 first number can be redundant for example: 111 234 or 333

But the next 7 numbers can't be redundant like 2222222 or 6666666

Im not a superhero with regex. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Why would you validate that? There are plenty of valid phone numbers that contain all the same digit.

Answer (score 1):

We can make use of back references to create a fairly small formula:

```
REGEX(Phone, "(\\d)\\1{6}")
```

Where `\\d` represents a digit, `(...)` is a capture group, `\\1` is a back-reference to a capture group (1 being the first), and `{6}` meaning "six times".

In other words, "find a digit, then find six additional copies of that digit in succession."

Note: The [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm#REGEX) clearly states:

> Capture groups and substitutions are ignored.

This is at least partly a lie. Capture groups do work, at least as far as back references are concerned.

Comment: Always interesting to find the undocumented features or errors in documentation.

Comment: @DaveHumm I've always assumed that the documentation was correct (it's said this for years), but I decided to try it today after writing an answer that was very disappointing. Discovering the docs were wrong made for a much shorter answer.